# How To make a discord bot which filters swear words

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

This is my current code:

```py
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive 
    
client = discord.Client()
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('!something'):
        await message.channel.send('SOMETHING')
    
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

I don't how I would make a swear filter. Where can I learn more about the `discord.py` library?

Comment: Why don't you [read the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#getting-started)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest using `commands.Bot()` instead of `discord.Client`. `commands.Bot()` is a subclass of `Client` so it has the same methods and attributes. With it, you can also set a command prefix instead of using `.startswith` all the time and much much more. anyways...

We are not here to write your code for you. Try looking it up or trying other solutions before asking a question. If you did show us what you tried, this gives us more information. Anyways, let's get back to writing your own code for you...

try this code:

```py
badWords = ['poopoo', 'peepee', 'check', 'today is my birthday', "i don't like undertale's music", 'you are not cool >:(']

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    messageContent = message.content
    if any(word.lower() in messageContent.lower().replace(' ', '') for word in badWords):
        await message.delete()
    #other stuff...
```

In this code, we are creating a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) and passing it to [`any()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any) which checks if any item in an iterable is `True`. If it does return `True` then the message is deleted.